# What is the force required to puncture through a sheet of foil against an anvil?

Tags: materials, steel, manufacturing-engineering, shear, forces

A hardened steel contour with a sharp edge presses against plastic foil which lies on top of a hardened steel anvil plate. What would be the force required to punch through the foil?

I am familiar with the general punching/blanking formula, however, as far as I know this only applies to punching into a die i.e. the countour goes fully through the sheet. A picture is added to further clearify the question.

General blanking formula:
\begin{equation}
 F = K*l*t*\tau
\end{equation}

where $K$ is a material/safety factor, $l$ the circomference of the contour, $t$ the sheet thickness and $\tau$ the shear stress.

[image]

Comment: So, you say the hardened steel tool has to go through the plastic and you state the formula is for a tool to go through material. Then why do you think it is not relevant?

Comment: The formula is for full puncturing. In this case the contour cannot fully pass through the foil. It can only press against a bottom anvil with the foil in between. I can imagine this might not match the given formula but I'm more than happy to be told otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Common plastic used in grocery shopping has an average shear strength of 200-500 psi. Or check the datasheet!

One could multiply this by the length of the cut, or perimeter of the circle.

A punching tool with a sharp edge and slanted strike can cut with much less force, but one has to be careful to halt the tool before it actually hard lands on the anvil!